# How to unit test removal of Flask.session attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, session, flask, mocking

I am trying to write a unit test to test a method inside my session module that purges an attribute called first_name from the session.

```
def purge_first_name():
    session.pop('first_name', None)
```

Here is my unit test class. It is failing on `assertIsNone`.

```
class SessionTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'testsecret'

    def test_purge_first_name_from_session(self):
        with self.app.test_client() as c:
                with c.session_transaction() as sess:
                    sess['first_name'] = 'Test'

                    with self.app.test_request_context():

                        self.assertEqual(sess['first_name'], 'Test')

                        purge_first_name()

                        self.assertIsNone(sess['first_name'])
```

Comment: this can be a silly question, but does purge know about sess object?

Answer (score 0):

Let modify your `flask_session.py` to show how to test

```
session = {}


def set_session(sess):
    session = sess


def purge_first_name():
    session.pop('first_name', None)
```

in your `test_flask_session.py`

```
def test_purge_first_name_from_session(self):
    with self.app.test_client() as c:
            with c.session_transaction() as sess:
                sess['first_name'] = 'Test'

                with self.app.test_request_context():

                    self.assertEqual(sess['first_name'], 'Test')
                    # set the module session to be sess
                    flask_session.set_session(sess)
                    flask_session.purge_first_name()
                    self.assertIsNone(flask_session.session.get('first_name', None))
```